# unload or destroy assetbundle manifest file in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to download assetbundle manifest file(with same name) from different url and replace it with current manifest file but when I download the file,error occurs saying that same file exist in the system.so I want to unload or destroy assetbundle manifest first before download it again.is it possible to change or replace the manifest file? (there is no unload method for assetbundle like in assetbundles)

Comment: do you want to unload manifest only or whole assetbundle?

Comment: actually I want to unload assetbundles from a specific scene in my game and load assetbundles from a different place(url).in that case I have to unload current manifest file to load new one.

Comment: no you only need to unload the assetbundle not manifest file